# Trying to write an IRC client but struggling to find a good resource regarding codes and connection protocol

Tags: c#, irc

I've looked at the RFC but I am still struggling. I've written a basic client in C# but I cannot find documentation for how to connect properly.

Once I connect and transmit NICK and USER information, I need to join a channel. If I do a JOIN straight away, nothing happens - presumably because it's too soon. I have to delay it, but I don't know which command I need to wait for to know it's okay to go ahead.

I get stuff like:

:irc.fish.net NOTICE AUTH :looking up your hostname...

and

:irc.fish.net 001 FishBot :Welcome

as well as stuff with codes 002, 003, 005, 251, 252, etc. but I can't find anywhere online that shows me what these are.

So my basic 2 questions are: What do you send a JOIN in response to, and where can I find what the IRC codes above correspond to? The RFC document was useless!

Comment: While it's a painful solution, you could always hook up MIRC (or whatever people use these days) to use Fiddler's proxy and you can see all of the traffic it req/acks from signing on to joining a room.

Comment: any final solution with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The RFC documents are certainly not useless!  You are correct that you need to send `USER` followed by `NICK`.  The `NOTICE` you are getting is that the IRC server is attempting to connect back to your PC via a protocol called `IDENTD`.  It's a relatively simple protocol but the upshot of it is that it wants to know that a program on the host that is connected to the server, is using the local/remote ports that the server has.

Chances are, your firewall is preventing this (and you're probably not running an IDENTD server).  This is not a huge problem, though a fully-fledged IRC client will implement it.  You can find out more [here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1413.html).  That goes in to much more detail.  It's relatively simple to implement.

Most IRC servers will give up if it cannot connect to you, and I've forgotten the *exact* side-effect of this (it has been a while), but the next messages you want to look out for are the MOTD_START/MOTD/MOTD_END and ERR_NOMOTD.  Only *after* you have received the end of the Message of the day, or handled the ERR_NOMOTD (there isn't one), can you then use `JOIN` to join channels.

Incidentally, this is a good RegEx for matching input from an IRC Server:

```
^(?:[:@]([^\\s]+) )?([^\\s]+)(?: ((?:[^:\\s][^\\s]* ?)*))?(?: ?:(.*))?$
```

The IRC RFCs list all the possible codes and what they mean.  I'm not sure why you think they are useless.  Which ones have you been referencing?

**EDIT**

I looked up my old C++ code for IRC so I could be a bit more helpful.  After connecting, it enters a stage (that I have labelled) negotiating:

Negotiating Stage:

1. If a password has been specified for the server, send it  `PASS mypassword`.
2. Send the `USER` command.
3. Enter the Negotiate Nickname Stage
4. Wait for `ERR_NOMOTD`, `END_OFMOTD`.  Until one of these comes, you're not "officially connected".

Negotiate Nickname Stage:

It's entirely possible that during connection, the nickname you want to use is already in use.  Therefore the client should:

1. Issue a `NICK` command
2. If you receive a `ERR_NICKINUSE` response, issue it again.  If you have no more nicknames to use, you can either bailout or prompt the user for another one.

Some other thing to consider:

- Look our for the `PING` command.  The server will send this when you're idle.  Handle this as high-priority and return `PONG` with the data the server gave you.  Failure to do this will ensure you get disconnected and when you're testing an IRC client, this can be a pain in the rear-end.

**Bonus Fun**

This is my enum for the IRC commands, you should be able to put this in to C# easily enough:

```
    // reply ids
    enum Reply
    {
        RplNone             = 0,
        // Initial
        RplWelcome          = 001,                  // :Welcome to the Internet Relay Network <nickname>
        RplYourHost         = 002,                  // :Your host is <server>, running version <ver>
        RplCreated          = 003,                  // :This server was created <datetime>
        RplMyInfo           = 004,                  // <server> <ver> <usermode> <chanmode>
        RplMap              = 005,                  // :map
        RplEndOfMap         = 007,                  // :End of /MAP
        RplMotdStart        = 375,                  // :- server Message of the Day
        RplMotd             = 372,                  // :- <info>
        RplMotdAlt          = 377,                  // :- <info>                                                                        (some)
        RplMotdAlt2         = 378,                  // :- <info>                                                                        (some)
        RplMotdEnd          = 376,                  // :End of /MOTD command.
        RplUModeIs          = 221,                  // <mode>

        // IsOn/UserHost
        RplUserHost         = 302,                  // :userhosts
        RplIsOn             = 303,                  // :nicknames

        // Away
        RplAway             = 301,                  // <nick> :away
        RplUnAway           = 305,                  // :You are no longer marked as being away
        RplNowAway          = 306,                  // :You have been marked as being away

        // WHOIS/WHOWAS
        RplWhoisHelper      = 310,                  // <nick> :looks very helpful                                                       DALNET
        RplWhoIsUser        = 311,                  // <nick> <username> <address> * :<info>
        RplWhoIsServer      = 312,                  // <nick> <server> :<info>
        RplWhoIsOperator    = 313,                  // <nick> :is an IRC Operator
        RplWhoIsIdle        = 317,                  // <nick> <seconds> <signon> :<info>
        RplEndOfWhois       = 318,                  // <request> :End of /WHOIS list.
        RplWhoIsChannels    = 319,                  // <nick> :<channels>
        RplWhoWasUser       = 314,                  // <nick> <username> <address> * :<info>
        RplEndOfWhoWas      = 369,                  // <request> :End of WHOWAS
        RplWhoReply         = 352,                  // <channel> <username> <address> <server> <nick> <flags> :<hops> <info>
        RplEndOfWho         = 315,                  // <request> :End of /WHO list.
        RplUserIPs          = 307,                  // :userips                                                                         UNDERNET
        RplUserIP           = 340,                  // <nick> :<nickname>=+<user>@<IP.address>                                          UNDERNET

        // List
        RplListStart        = 321,                  // Channel :Users Name
        RplList             = 322,                  // <channel> <users> :<topic>
        RplListEnd          = 323,                  // :End of /LIST
        RplLinks            = 364,                  // <server> <hub> :<hops> <info>
        RplEndOfLinks       = 365,                  // <mask> :End of /LINKS list.

        // Post-Channel Join
        RplUniqOpIs         = 325,
        RplChannelModeIs    = 324,                  // <channel> <mode>
        RplChannelUrl       = 328,                  // <channel> :url                                                                   DALNET
        RplChannelCreated   = 329,                  // <channel> <time>
        RplNoTopic          = 331,                  // <channel> :No topic is set.
        RplTopic            = 332,                  // <channel> :<topic>
        RplTopicSetBy       = 333,                  // <channel> <nickname> <time>
        RplNamReply         = 353,                  // = <channel> :<names>
        RplEndOfNames       = 366,                  // <channel> :End of /NAMES list.

        // Invitational
        RplInviting         = 341,                  // <nick> <channel>
        RplSummoning        = 342,

        // Channel Lists
        RplInviteList       = 346,                  // <channel> <invite> <nick> <time>                                                 IRCNET
        RplEndOfInviteList  = 357,                  // <channel> :End of Channel Invite List                                            IRCNET
        RplExceptList       = 348,                  // <channel> <exception> <nick> <time>                                              IRCNET
        RplEndOfExceptList  = 349,                  // <channel> :End of Channel Exception List                                         IRCNET
        RplBanList          = 367,                  // <channel> <ban> <nick> <time>
        RplEndOfBanList     = 368,                  // <channel> :End of Channel Ban List


        // server/misc
        RplVersion          = 351,                  // <version>.<debug> <server> :<info>
        RplInfo             = 371,                  // :<info>
        RplEndOfInfo        = 374,                  // :End of /INFO list.
        RplYoureOper        = 381,                  // :You are now an IRC Operator
        RplRehashing        = 382,                  // <file> :Rehashing
        RplYoureService     = 383,
        RplTime             = 391,                  // <server> :<time>
        RplUsersStart       = 392,
        RplUsers            = 393,
        RplEndOfUsers       = 394,
        RplNoUsers          = 395,
        RplServList         = 234,
        RplServListEnd      = 235,
        RplAdminMe          = 256,                  // :Administrative info about server
        RplAdminLoc1        = 257,                  // :<info>
        RplAdminLoc2        = 258,                  // :<info>
        RplAdminEMail       = 259,                  // :<info>
        RplTryAgain         = 263,                  // :Server load is temporarily too heavy. Please wait a while and try again.

        // tracing
        RplTraceLink        = 200,
        RplTraceConnecting  = 201,
        RplTraceHandshake   = 202,
        RplTraceUnknown     = 203,
        RplTraceOperator    = 204,
        RplTraceUser        = 205,
        RplTraceServer      = 206,
        RplTraceService     = 207,
        RplTraceNewType     = 208,
        RplTraceClass       = 209,
        RplTraceReconnect   = 210,
        RplTraceLog         = 261,
        RplTraceEnd         = 262,

        // stats
        RplStatsLinkInfo    = 211,                  // <connection> <sendq> <sentmsg> <sentbyte> <recdmsg> <recdbyte> :<open>
        RplStatsCommands    = 212,                  // <command> <uses> <bytes>
        RplStatsCLine       = 213,                  // C <address> * <server> <port> <class>
        RplStatsNLine       = 214,                  // N <address> * <server> <port> <class>
        RplStatsILine       = 215,                  // I <ipmask> * <hostmask> <port> <class>
        RplStatsKLine       = 216,                  // k <address> * <username> <details>
        RplStatsPLine       = 217,                  // P <port> <??> <??>
        RplStatsQLine       = 222,                  // <mask> :<comment>
        RplStatsELine       = 223,                  // E <hostmask> * <username> <??> <??>
        RplStatsDLine       = 224,                  // D <ipmask> * <username> <??> <??>
        RplStatsLLine       = 241,                  // L <address> * <server> <??> <??>
        RplStatsuLine       = 242,                  // :Server Up <num> days, <time>
        RplStatsoLine       = 243,                  // o <mask> <password> <user> <??> <class>
        RplStatsHLine       = 244,                  // H <address> * <server> <??> <??>
        RplStatsGLine       = 247,                  // G <address> <timestamp> :<reason>
        RplStatsULine       = 248,                  // U <host> * <??> <??> <??>
        RplStatsZLine       = 249,                  // :info
        RplStatsYLine       = 218,                  // Y <class> <ping> <freq> <maxconnect> <sendq>
        RplEndOfStats       = 219,                  // <char> :End of /STATS report
        RplStatsUptime      = 242,

        // GLINE
        RplGLineList        = 280,                  // <address> <timestamp> <reason>                                                   UNDERNET
        RplEndOfGLineList   = 281,                  // :End of G-line List                                                              UNDERNET

        // Silence
        RplSilenceList      = 271,                  // <nick> <mask>                                                                    UNDERNET/DALNET
        RplEndOfSilenceList = 272,                  // <nick> :End of Silence List                                                      UNDERNET/DALNET

        // LUser
        RplLUserClient      = 251,                  // :There are <user> users and <invis> invisible on <serv> servers
        RplLUserOp          = 252,                  // <num> :operator(s) online
        RplLUserUnknown     = 253,                  // <num> :unknown connection(s)
        RplLUserChannels    = 254,                  // <num> :channels formed
        RplLUserMe          = 255,                  // :I have <user> clients and <serv> servers
        RplLUserLocalUser   = 265,                  // :Current local users: <curr> Max: <max>
        RplLUserGlobalUser  = 266,                  // :Current global users: <curr> Max: <max>


        // Errors
        ErrNoSuchNick       = 401,                  // <nickname> :No such nick
        ErrNoSuchServer     = 402,                  // <server> :No such server
        ErrNoSuchChannel    = 403,                  // <channel> :No such channel
        ErrCannotSendToChan = 404,                  // <channel> :Cannot send to channel
        ErrTooManyChannels  = 405,                  // <channel> :You have joined too many channels
        ErrWasNoSuchNick    = 406,                  // <nickname> :There was no such nickname
        ErrTooManyTargets   = 407,                  // <target> :Duplicate recipients. No message delivered
        ErrNoColors         = 408,                  // <nickname> #<channel> :You cannot use colors on this channel. Not sent: <text>   DALNET
        ErrNoOrigin         = 409,                  // :No origin specified
        ErrNoRecipient      = 411,                  // :No recipient given (<command>)
        ErrNoTextToSend     = 412,                  // :No text to send
        ErrNoTopLevel       = 413,                  // <mask> :No toplevel domain specified
        ErrWildTopLevel     = 414,                  // <mask> :Wildcard in toplevel Domain
        ErrBadMask          = 415,
        ErrTooMuchInfo      = 416,                  // <command> :Too many lines in the output, restrict your query                     UNDERNET
        ErrUnknownCommand   = 421,                  // <command> :Unknown command
        ErrNoMotd           = 422,                  // :MOTD File is missing
        ErrNoAdminInfo      = 423,                  // <server> :No administrative info available
        ErrFileError        = 424,
        ErrNoNicknameGiven  = 431,                  // :No nickname given
        ErrErroneusNickname = 432,                  // <nickname> :Erroneus Nickname
        ErrNickNameInUse    = 433,                  // <nickname> :Nickname is already in use.
        ErrNickCollision    = 436,                  // <nickname> :Nickname collision KILL
        ErrUnAvailResource  = 437,                  // <channel> :Cannot change nickname while banned on channel
        ErrNickTooFast      = 438,                  // <nick> :Nick change too fast. Please wait <sec> seconds.                         (most)
        ErrTargetTooFast    = 439,                  // <target> :Target change too fast. Please wait <sec> seconds.                     DALNET/UNDERNET
        ErrUserNotInChannel = 441,                  // <nickname> <channel> :They aren't on that channel
        ErrNotOnChannel     = 442,                  // <channel> :You're not on that channel
        ErrUserOnChannel    = 443,                  // <nickname> <channel> :is already on channel
        ErrNoLogin          = 444,
        ErrSummonDisabled   = 445,                  // :SUMMON has been disabled
        ErrUsersDisabled    = 446,                  // :USERS has been disabled
        ErrNotRegistered    = 451,                  // <command> :Register first.
        ErrNeedMoreParams   = 461,                  // <command> :Not enough parameters
        ErrAlreadyRegistered= 462,                  // :You may not reregister
        ErrNoPermForHost    = 463,
        ErrPasswdMistmatch  = 464,
        ErrYoureBannedCreep = 465,
        ErrYouWillBeBanned  = 466,
        ErrKeySet           = 467,                  // <channel> :Channel key already set
        ErrServerCanChange  = 468,                  // <channel> :Only servers can change that mode                                     DALNET
        ErrChannelIsFull    = 471,                  // <channel> :Cannot join channel (+l)
        ErrUnknownMode      = 472,                  // <char> :is unknown mode char to me
        ErrInviteOnlyChan   = 473,                  // <channel> :Cannot join channel (+i)
        ErrBannedFromChan   = 474,                  // <channel> :Cannot join channel (+b)
        ErrBadChannelKey    = 475,                  // <channel> :Cannot join channel (+k)
        ErrBadChanMask      = 476,
        ErrNickNotRegistered= 477,                  // <channel> :You need a registered nick to join that channel.                      DALNET
        ErrBanListFull      = 478,                  // <channel> <ban> :Channel ban/ignore list is full
        ErrNoPrivileges     = 481,                  // :Permission Denied- You're not an IRC operator
        ErrChanOPrivsNeeded = 482,                  // <channel> :You're not channel operator
        ErrCantKillServer   = 483,                  // :You cant kill a server!
        ErrRestricted       = 484,                  // <nick> <channel> :Cannot kill, kick or deop channel service                      UNDERNET
        ErrUniqOPrivsNeeded = 485,                  // <channel> :Cannot join channel (reason)
        ErrNoOperHost       = 491,                  // :No O-lines for your host
        ErrUModeUnknownFlag = 501,                  // :Unknown MODE flag
        ErrUsersDontMatch   = 502,                  // :Cant change mode for other users
        ErrSilenceListFull  = 511                   // <mask> :Your silence list is full                                                UNDERNET/DALNET

    };  // eo enum Reply
```

Comment: Cheers, I thought about waiting for end of MOTD but it seemed a bit hacky. Thanks for the command list!

Comment: It's not hacky at all.  Until it has arrived (or the server hasn't got one), you're not in a "state" to send commands, so it ends up being the perfect candidate to watch for to know when to issue commands.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you looked at an old version ([RFC 1459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459)) instead of the current version ([RFC 2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812)) of the standard?

The latter one lists the numeric codes in Section 5 "Replies":

```
   001    RPL_WELCOME
          "Welcome to the Internet Relay Network
           <nick>!<user>@<host>"
   002    RPL_YOURHOST
          "Your host is <servername>, running version <ver>"
   003    RPL_CREATED
          "This server was created <date>"
   ...
```

(That should answer your second question; unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with the protocol to answer your first. A simple solution to get you on the right track might be to trace the connection of an existing IRC client using some [packet sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer).)

Answer (score 2):

The codes can be found in [this document](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc2812.txt), the ones you specified are:

- 002    RPL_YOURHOST "Your host is , running version "
- 003    RPL_CREATED "This server was created "
- 005    RPL_BOUNCE "Try server , port "
- 251    RPL_LUSERCLIENT ":There are  users and  services on  servers"
- 252    RPL_LUSEROP " :operator(s) online"